# Fatal error: Class 'Html' not found Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So for the past few hours I've been having some issues, I'm unable to use Html and I cannot access my css stylesheet.

`Fatal error: Class 'Html' not found`

This is the error I get.

I followed this tutorial: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/fatal-error-class-illuminatehtmlhtmlserviceprovider-not-found-in-laravel-51 and it doesn't work.

I get returned a 404 error when trying to access my css, it's there in `css/main.css`

**Edit**: Code:

```
{!! Html::style(asset('css/main.css')) !!}

<p>
  Hello
</p>
```

Comment: I'll add code in the question.

Comment: Is your css stored inside assets?

Comment: `Fatal error: Class 'HTML' not found` when I use `HTML::style`

Comment: and yes my css is inside assets

Comment: `Html::style('assets/css/main.css');`

Comment: `Fatal error: Class 'Html' not found` when I use `Html::style('assets/css/main.css')`

Comment: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{!! asset('css/main.css') !!}" >'

Comment: I've tried that aswell, still returning 404 :(

Comment: Do you push main.css in public/css/main.css?

Comment: No, it's inside resources/assets/css/main.css

Comment: That's reason return 404, you should copy main.css to public/css or use gulp or elixir mix css file

Comment: Oh okay. I'll try it out

Comment: That fixes the 404 but I still don't have a fix for anything else :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add line to **composer.json** :

```
 "illuminate/html": "5.*"
```

Update composer :

```
composer update
```

Add line to the app.php array providers :

```
'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

Add line to the app.php array aliases :

```
'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
```

Now it works!

Comment: Still getting the same error. `Fatal error: Class 'Html' not found`

Comment: check in aliases array what you write  because may be it is case sensitive **HTML =>** or **Html =>**

Comment: It's there but as `'Html'`

Comment: try to use in {{  }}

Comment: As I stated in my question, I tried that already. also a failure.